# Get data from Text file Print to Label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Just to keep this short I am working on a simple game to be played with anyone in the world who be interested in it, and because I am creating said game I decided to work on a simple launcher for the game one that pings the website for a version, checks that version with a stored text file with the game already installed and see if its a difference in version. If its a difference in version the launcher downloads the game. If the person does not already have the game installed it downloads the game for them.

Now for my problem why I am posting here, I am trying to get the text file already stored on the computer from the AppData directory to be read by the launcher and use it as an comparison with the version on the website. This is what I have for the on launch:

On Launch:

```vb
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim wc As New Net.WebClient

Text = wc.DownloadString("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47132467/version.txt")

If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Program Files\SC\SC.exe") Then
    StartBtn.Enabled = True
    StartBtn.Visible = True
Else
    StartBtn.Enabled = False
    StartBtn.Visible = False
End If

If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Program Files\SC\Readme.txt") Then
    ReadMeBtn.Visible = True
Else
    ReadMeBtn.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

In short I am trying to figure out how to make a text file from the computer itself stored in AppData under `Environ("AppData") & "\SC\version.txt"` Been trying to figure out how to get the program to Read the local stored text file and put it as a variable where the program will compare it with the text file online. Thanks in Advanced! Sorry if I confuse anyone my brain is in derp mode trying to figure this out for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 Functions Read & Write:

```
Public Function GetFileContents(ByVal FullPath As String, _
   Optional ByRef ErrInfo As String = "") As String

    Dim strContents As String
    Dim objReader As StreamReader
    Try

        objReader = New StreamReader(FullPath)
        strContents = objReader.ReadToEnd()
        objReader.Close()
        Return strContents
    Catch Ex As Exception
        ErrInfo = Ex.Message
    End Try
End Function

Public Function SaveTextToFile(ByVal strData As String, _
 ByVal FullPath As String, _
   Optional ByVal ErrInfo As String = "") As Boolean

    Dim Contents As String
    Dim bAns As Boolean = False
    Dim objReader As StreamWriter
    Try

        objReader = New StreamWriter(FullPath)
        objReader.Write(strData)
        objReader.Close()
        bAns = True
    Catch Ex As Exception
        ErrInfo = Ex.Message

    End Try
    Return bAns
End Function
```

Call:

```
Dim File_Path as string = Environ("AppData") & "\SC\version.txt"
Dim versionStr as String = GetFileContents("File_Path")
Label1.text = versionStr
Label1.text.refresh ''// Sometimes this may be required depending on what you are doing!
```

Comment: You would simply CALL: `GetFileContents("File_Path")` which would return the contents of the file (`strContents`).
.

    `Dim File_Path as string = Environ("AppData") & "\SC\version.txt"
    
    GetFileContents("File_Path")`

Comment: Thanks Stitch!, I would upvote your response but sadly I cannot =/ It helped.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read the version directly, rather than a text file, have a look at this code:

```
   If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(fn) Then

        Dim fv As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fn)

        If fv Is Nothing Then Return -1 'file has no version info

        Return fv.FileMajorPart * 100000 + fv.FileMinorPart * 1000 + fv.FileBuildPart

    Else
        Return 0 'file does not exist
    End If
```